# Linux - numerical sort then overwrite file

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I have a csv file with a general format

```
date,  
2013.04.04,
2013.04.04,
2012.04.02,
2013.02.01,
2013.04.05,
2013.04.02,
```

a script I run will add data to this file which will not necessarily be in date order. How can I sort the file into date order (ignoring the header) and overwrite the existing file rather than writing to STDOUT

I have used awk

```
awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -n"}' file > file_sorted
mv file_sorted file
```

Is there a more effective way to do this without creating an additional file and moving?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
sort -n -o your_file your_file
```

`-o` defines the output file and is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/sort.html), so it is safe to use (no original file mangled).

**Output**

```
$ cat s
date,  
2013.04.04,
2013.04.04,
2012.04.02,
2013.02.01,
2013.04.05,
2013.04.02,

$ sort -n -o s s

$ cat s
date,  
2012.04.02,
2013.02.01,
2013.04.02,
2013.04.04,
2013.04.04,
2013.04.05,
```

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate on why this does not mangle the file (like a lot of other commands do when reading from and writing to the same file). Does `-o` magically prevent files from being mangled like `sed -i`? To me it seems like `sort` just doesn't start to output until everything was read because the last line could always be the first in the sorted ouput. I guess it could fail when using `sort` in `--merge` mode. If I'm right `-o` is just as good as a shell redirection `>`.

Comment: @Socowi good question! This is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/sort.html). You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244387/1983854) to the question *How to sort a file in-place*.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the links. The note »*This file can be the same as one of the input files.*« was not given in my `man sort` so I thought there would be no guarantees.

Comment: @Freedo that your original does not get truncated by error and left you with an empty file

Answer (score 2):

Note that there exists a race condition if the script and the sorting is running at the same time.

If the file header sorts before the data, you can use the solution suggested by *fedorqui* as `sort -o file file` is safe (at least with GNU sort, see `info sort`).

Running `sort` from within `awk` seems kind of convoluted, another alternative would be to use `head` and `tail` (assuming bash shell):

```
{ head -n1 file; tail -n+2 file | sort -n; } > file_sorted
```

Now, about replacing the existing file. AFAIK, You have two options, create a new file and replace old file with new as you describe in your question, or you could use `sponge` from `moreutils` like this:

```
{ head -n1 file; tail -n+2 file | sort -n; } | sponge file
```

Note that `sponge` still creates a temporary file.

Comment: Thanks I had never heard of sponge before now

Comment: @glennjackman: I was testing in zsh which doesn't have these requirements. Thanks for fixing it.