# Most efficient way to add non-unique data to unique data in bash

Tags: bash

I have a massive file with each line being unique. I have a collection of smaller files (but still relatively large) where the lines are not unique. This collection is constantly growing. I need to add the small files into the big file and make sure there are no duplicates in the big file. Right now what I do is add all the files into one, and then run sort -u on it. However this ends up rescanning the entire big file which takes longer and longer as more files come in, and seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does each line have a smaller unique key?  This sounds like you should be using a simple database, like dbm.

Comment: @cdarke Unfortunately I don't have a choice as to how the data is stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the big file is already sorted, it would be more efficient to `sort -u` *only* the smaller files, and then `sort -u -m` (merge) the result with the big file. `-m` assumes the inputs are already individually sorted.

Example (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Merges unique lines in the files passed as arguments into BIGFILE.

BIGFILE=bigfile.txt
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
trap "rm $TMPFILE" EXIT

sort -u "$@" > "$TMPFILE"
sort -um "$TMPFILE" "$BIGFILE" -o "$BIGFILE"
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244408/113632) explains why `-o` is necessary.

---

If you like process substitutions you can even do it in a one-liner:

```
sort -um <(sort -u "$@") "$BIGFILE" -o "$BIGFILE"
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for