# bash: sort applied to a file returns right results as terminal output, but does change the file itself

Tags: bash, sorting

I am using this command

```
sort -k1 -n source-g5.txt
```

to sort the content of file tmp-source-g5.txt (n rows, 2 columns) according to the numerical value of the first column.

When I run that line, the terminal prints out the desired result, but as I try to save the result into the same file,

```
sort -k1 -n source-g5.txt > source-g5.txt
```

the file shows no difference from before.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes, but one does not understand what one is doing wrong until one realises the problem lies in redirecting the output to the source file.

Comment: hte thread I linked can also be a possible duplicate.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies the problem with `sort -k1 -n source-g5.txt > source-g5.txt` and provides a link to details of what to do about it ([SC2094 -  Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline.](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2094)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244351/how-to-sort-a-file-in-place) it turns out that redirecting the output of sort into the same file from which sort reads as source will not work since

> the shell is makes the redirections (not the sort(1) program) and the
> input file (as being the output also) will be erased just before
> giving the sort(1) program the opportunity of reading it.

So I have split my command into two

```
sort -k1 -n source-g5.txt > tmp-source-g5.txt
mv tmp-source-g5.txt > source-g5.txt
```

Comment: I forgot `cat`, thanks! question updated

Comment: well, `mv` is even better! question updated